# Why getting the first blood is so important?

Tags: league-of-legends

At the beginning of the matches, we always see both teams just rush, in hope to get that first blood.

After the first blood happened, it seems both teams tone down a little the offense.

So why do teams want the first blood so bad?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstblood in a competetive match means more gold for everybody, which results ina ll 3 lanes having wards from minute 1 on! This is very important since the enemy jungler cant gank anymore.

In Soloq, FB raises the moral of your own team, and morale one of the biggest factors for who is gonna win.

Answer (score 1):

Extra 100 gold, and getting first blood is a good way to start the snowballing